# Alias in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this query which contains alias in the where clause but it says unknown column. Here's the column :

```
select a.asofdate, pi.PShipEntID,  ass.firmentid, ass.firmorindentid, concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) roles,
    case when roles like '%(BM)%' then concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) else null end boardmember,
    case when concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) like '%(BO)%' then concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) else null end boardobserver,
    case when concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) like '%(PRP)%' then concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) else null end primaryresponsiblepartner,
    case when concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) like '%(SRP)%' then concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) else null end secondaryresponsiblepartner
    from asofdates a
left join associations ass
on a.asofdate > ass.StartDate
left join pshipinvestments pi
on pi.CompEntID = ass.FirmEntID
left join entities e 
on ass.firmorindentid = e.InvEntID
left join individuals ind
on ind.indentid = e.InvEntID
```

I understand this query is a pain and that I can't have aliases in the cases  but is there anyway where this query can be simplified instead of using the complex expression for concatenating everywhere?
As in replace this expression `concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle))` with an aliasname in the case statements. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the where clause?

Comment: Sorry cases, my bad.

Comment: A MySQL special trick is to use the `HAVING` clause for such column alias conditions.

Comment: Did you get this solved in the end?

Comment: Nope, I had to change the query itself as it was getting too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help.

```
select * from (your above mentioned query)
```

and then use this in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make yuorself a subquery and do the work there once. Then you can use the column over and over. Check the below, obviously I can't run it because you haven'tt provided any sample data :)

```
select a.asofdate, pi.PShipEntID,  ass.firmentid, ass.firmorindentid,
a.Name roles,
    case when roles like '%(BM)%' then a.Name else null end boardmember,
    case when a.Name like '%(BO)%' then a.Name else null end boardobserver,
    case when a.Name like '%(PRP)%' then a.Name else null end primaryresponsiblepartner,
    case when a.Name like '%(SRP)%' then a.Name else null end secondaryresponsiblepartner
    from
    (
    select
    concat(concat(substring(ind.FirstName, 1, 1),' ',ind.lastname, ' '),initials(ass.empltitle)) as Name,
    *   
    asofdates
    ) a
left join associations ass
on a.asofdate > ass.StartDate
left join pshipinvestments pi
on pi.CompEntID = ass.FirmEntID
left join entities e 
on ass.firmorindentid = e.InvEntID
left join individuals ind
on ind.indentid = e.InvEntID
where a.Name = 'Albert'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `where` clause.

However, MySQL extends the use of `having` to work with non-aggregation queries.  And it can use aliases.

So, you can use:

```
having boardobserver = @boardobserver
```